# return the value before / char Vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have many names some of them has / char and some of them without
so I need to copy the names unit the / to a new column

my data not limited more than 300
what I mean not a specific range .. sometimes more sometimes less

I try this code but not work for all the items and not so good
can please give any suggestions

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String



str1 = Range("B2").Value
x = 1
Do Until str2 = "/"
If x = Len(str1) + 2 Then GoTo OUT
str2 = Mid(str1, x, 1)
x = x + 1
Loop
OUT:
Range("E2").Value = Left(str1, x - 2)
End Sub
```

[image: Example of data]

Comment: Please note that this can be done with a simple formula, without VBA. Is VBA a necessity?

Comment: `Goto OUT` can be swapped for `Exit Do`.

Comment: As @BigBen said... `=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(B1,FIND("/",B1)-1)),B1)`

Comment: thank you @BigBen , yes necessity because this just part I will do the rest

Comment: Then write the formula provided by @DarrenBartrup-Cook to the entire range using VBA. It seems like your current attempt is overcomplicating things.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook same just take one value

Answer (score 0):

### Split Cells

- This can be done in various ways much more efficiently as mentioned in the comments.
- This is an introductory code that illustrates various subjects:

  - use `Options Explicit` (declare all variables),
  - use constants,
  - calculate the last 'occupied' row in a column,
  - use a `For...Next Loop`,
  - use `Range.Cells`,
  - and use text functions like `Instr`, `Trim`, `Left`, and `Right`.
- `'*` indicates the only differences between the two codes. To simplify, you can copy both lines from the second to the first code appropriately.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub getName()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Delimiter As String = "/"
    
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim sString As String
    Dim Pos As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        sString = Cells(i, "B").Value
        Pos = InStr(1, sString, Delimiter)
        If Pos > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "E") = Trim(Left(sString, Pos - 1)) '*
        Else
            Cells(i, "E") = Trim(sString) '*
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub

Sub getLastName()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Delimiter As String = "/"
    
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim sString As String
    Dim Pos As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        sString = CStr(Cells(i, "B").Value)
        Pos = InStr(1, sString, Delimiter)
        If Pos > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "F") = Trim(Right(sString, Len(sString) - Pos)) '*
        Else
            Cells(i, "F") = "" '*
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```